# Filter Power BI table based on a column being less than another

Tags: report, powerbi

I've been trying to filter a table on Power BI based on the value of two columns.

The expression would be FILTER table where ColumnB < ColumnA.

(And if possible)
And column b is not negative.

The advanced filter only allows numbers, so I suppose is with an expression buy I'm not sure yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could achieve this by adding a conditional column in your data... and later use this col as your filter!

Comment: Yes! I came here to say that I figure it out, thank you, very much!!